# Как на django rest framework реализовать отправку писем на почты через определённый промежуток времени

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Как на django rest framework реализовать отправку писем на почты через определённый промежуток времени

Comment: [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) хорош в этом отношении

Comment: есть варианту по-мимо celery?